# Can't run postfix on Mountain Lion due to missing system_user_maps.db

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, postfix

When I start postfix, I see in `/var/log/system.log` the following error:

`error: open database /etc/postfix/system_user_maps.db: No such file or directory`

How should this file be created so that postfix can start properly?

Comment: First of all, do you have an `/etc/postfix`? A program wanting you to create its initial database for it is _weird._ (Then again, so is wanting you to create its `/etc` subdir, but at least that's trivial.)

Comment: Of course I do.

Comment: \*chuckles\* Just checking. Didn't want you to waste time if it was just complaining for lack of an empty directory. That said, have you tried creating an empty file with that name?

Comment: I did a `touch` on that file. Now I get `warning: hash:/etc/postfix/system_user_maps is unavailable. open database /etc/postfix/system_user_maps.db: Inappropriate file type or format`

Comment: Grrrrr. Okay. What version of `postfix`? And does the manual say anything? Also, where did you get it from? I found something that suggests that the database should be created in a configuration phase at install time.

Comment: This is the built-in postfix. I upgraded from Lion to Mountain Lion and now nothing works.

Comment: Aha: [Apple apparently overwrites certain configs in Mountain Lion.](http://blog.deversus.com/2012/07/fix-for-postfix-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/)

Comment: Maybe also try [`sudo postmap /etc/postfix/system_user_maps.db`](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5028969).

Comment: Tried all of the above, to no avail. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Sure…sorry I wasn't of more help.